# set a void key in php array token Attributes Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, twig

So in symfony 4, there is a token that have a Attribute array we can fill. So i have fill it with some Data by using

```
$something = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->setAttribute(
    $idValueProduct[0], $quantityValueProduct[0]
);
```

And there is no problem about it.

The problem is when I want to unset a key in AttributeArray in the key, there is no method in `Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken` to do this like in PHP.

So my question is: **is there a trick** by using `setAttribute` method for destroy a key in my `token.Attributes`?

Comment: Are you using Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\?

Comment: No it does't seems like i'm using use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\ But Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken;

Comment: If you are working with Symfony 4, you are probably using jwtoken and using that bundle for that. If you are using that bundle, you can decode the token, remove the attribute and encode it again easily. But ok.

Comment: I will try it, thanks a lot !